# What is proper time for drinking water with meal?

Tags: nutrition, diet, digestion

I've gone through many articles on Google.

One says it's good to drink water after meal as it aids digestion while others say never drink water after a meal because it will dilute the acids (i.e. HCl).

I am a teenager and want to gain weight. Is it beneficial to drink water immediately after a meal (as I usually do)?

What is actually going on there?

Comment: Strongly related: [Drinking water during or after Meal](http://health.stackexchange.com/questions/1060/drinking-water-during-or-after-meal?rq=1)

Comment: You don't have to drink anything at all if your food has enough water content. But I know some people who feel really uncomfortable after eating if they don't drink.